# How can i attach a matrix to an image in react native?

Tags: react-native, maps, coordinates, pinchzoom

I'm starting a new proyect and i don't know how to aim my solution properly so i hope somebody can enlighten me. The proyect consist on a shopping mall map (an image), where there's gonna be location pins in each shop. The problem is that i want the user to be able to zoom in and out, and move the map in all direction, but the location pins should stay in place and not be affected by scale. How can i implement a "local coordinates system"? Should i make a matrix and attach it to the map? What libraries should i check? I'm quite new and pretty lost, hope you can help me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ojHU.jpg)